# Is there a way to revive an old question to see if the answers might have changed?

Tags: discussion

I've been doing some django work recently, and came across this question: [models.py getting huge, what is the best way to break it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160579/models-py-getting-huge-what-is-the-best-way-to-break-it-up)

The top voted answer is unedited and about 6 years old. The accepted answer is last edited about 5 years old.

Now, I'm not sure this is the case, but I'd be willing to put money that the answers are different today than they were back then. For example, Glenn refers to a bug in Django, and hopefully that's taken care of now.

Is there a good way to bring this question to the attention of the general public, perhaps because it has a newer, better answer?

Comment: Why not make a new question linking that question in your question and explain that you're checking if that solution is still valid. If it is delete/close your question?

Comment: If you are unsure if the answers are outdated, post a comment on the question or one of the answers. If you know they are outdated, post an updated answer

Comment: You could offer a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: In that specific case, per the linked cookbook page, the issue has been fixed and `Meta` isn't needed. I've added a note to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, if there's an old question you'd like more answers for, you can offer a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), trading a chunk of your own reputation for more attention on the question (it will appear in the Featured list).

You could also comment on the answers, asking the author if there's any update (just do this once per answer, people may have moved on).

Finally, if you can add more information to the question *without changing it*, do so; the edit will bump the question back into the activity views, so you may get more eyes that way, and the additional info may mean you get better answers.

---

In that specific case, the bug had indeed been fixed and I've added a note to clarify which versions it applies to. Luckily someone had commented with a link to a cookbook page that linked to the bug, so it was pretty easy to figure out!

Otherwise, the two top answers (split into separate apps and/or make `models` a package) are still up-to-date.